# How to add external helm as part of my helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My helm depends on another helm from public repository. I've installed it manually and put the command to documentation. But I'd like to do it automatically.

Is there some way to set such dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may take a look on helm [chart dependencies](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#chart-dependencies) with [requirements.yaml](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_best_practices/#requirements-files)
And as an example - [Kafka helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/requirements.yaml) with zookeeper dependency.